# java- How to build the executable for the applet application

Tags: java, applet

I implemented the java applet application. I searching for the process of how to create the executable file for this application.I am not find any good solution. Please can anybody help me.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Java applet application"? It's really not clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You could launch it via the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer

Comment: i am creating the applet. that contains the 2 text areas and one button.Now i want to create the executable file for this applet. it means if you copy that file into your system and after run that executable file then the applet will be run. is it possible? if yes then how to do it.please help me

Comment: I implemented this using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable of a Java applet is either a `.jar` file, or the `.class` directory.

You execute a Java applet within a web page.  You place the `.jar` file or the `.class` directory in your web directory structure.

Here's an example HTML applet:

```
<applet code=NameOfApplet.class name=NameOfApplet archive=NameOfApplet.jar
    width=300 height=300>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

Further information can be found at [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#api).

It's been a while since I've had to code an applet, but the archive parameter can include directories.

Comment: It means we need to create the jar file this applet and after that we need to past that jar file into ur system and then create the html file using ur code after that run the app using cmd is it right?

Comment: @naresh: Nope.  You have to create a web site directory on a computer that has an HTTP server, like Apache.  You have to create a web page, and put that page on the web site directory.  Then you create your applet .jar, using Eclipse.  Finally, you move the applet .jar so it's in the same web page directory as your web page.  Put the applet HTML in your web page.  Execute the web page using your favorite browser.

Comment: @naresh: It sounds like what you really want is a Windows application you can run from the command line, rather than a web page applet.  Look at JFrame to create a Windows application.

Comment: 1) `NameOfApplet.class` The code parameter should be the fully qualified class name, i.e. just `NameOfApplet` 2) *'the archive parameter can include directories."*  No it can't.  The `archive` attribute is for archives - loose class files might be loaded from the `codebase` (which in the case of that HTML, defaults to the directory in which the HTML is located).

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of creating an `Applet` or `JApplet`, create a `JFrame`.
- Jar the classes.
- Add a manifest file that specifies the main-class
- Double click the Jar to launch.

---

If you would like to make it a nicer experience for the end user, create a web page that uses [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to check that a suitable JRE is installed, then launch the `JFrame` using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, if you want to run the applet outside the browser, you can create the JAR file normally and then user [appletviewer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Executable applet is nothing but the .class file of the applet, which is obtained by compiling the source code of the applet. Compiling an applet is exactly the same as compiling an application. Therefore, we can use the Java compiler to compile the applet.

Assume that we have created a file called HelloJava.java for our applet. Here are the steps required for compiling the HelloJava applet.

1. Move to the directory containing the source code and type the following command: javac HelloJava.java
2. The compiled output file called HelloJava.class is placed in the same directory as the source.
3. If any error message is received, then we must check for errors, correct them and compile the applet again.